# Using get_terms() with meta_query parameters

Tags: meta-query, terms, meta-value, term-meta

Im trying to build a taxonomy query to only display the terms that have a certain custom field value assigned to it. The custom field holds a boolean value, so I tried:

```
$args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'meta_key' => 'featured',
        'meta_value' => true
    );
```

Also:

```
$args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'meta_query' => array(
             array(
                'key'       => 'featured',
                'value'     => true,
                'compare'   => '='
             )
        )
    );
```

None of these returned the expected results. What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Inserting boolean term meta values

When we add non-existent *term meta* with e.g.

```
add_term_meta( 123, 'test', true );
```

then we are actually running the following insert :

```
$wpdb->insert( 'wp_termmeta', array(
   'term_id' => 123,
   'meta_key' => 'test',
   'meta_value' => true
) );
```

within the general `add_metadata()` function.

Now `wpdb::insert()` is actually a wrapper for `wpdb::_insert_replace_helper()`
that prepares the SQL insert query and maps the insert values to:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_termmeta` (`term_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (%d, %s, %s)
```

or in our test case:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_termmeta` (`term_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (123, 'test', '1')
```

Also note that the `meta_value` column is of *longtext* type in the `wp_termmeta` table.

So the boolean `true` is stored as the `'1'` string.

### Fetching boolean term meta values

When `get_terms()` runs with this kind of meta query:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'meta_query' => array(
         array(
            'key'       => 'featured',
            'value'     => true,
            'compare'   => '='
         )
    )
);
```

then the generated SQL query contains:

```
wp_termmeta.meta_key = 'featured' AND wp_termmeta.meta_value = '1'
```

where the `true` (bool) is converted to the `'1'` (string).

Comment: I still can't make query return any result, using a string `"1"` as the value passed to the meta_query but i'll keep looking. Thank you so much for the detailed explanation though.

Comment: The `true` meta value in the `get_terms()` query is also changed to `'1'` so I think you must be saving the term meta values differently. How do you store it? What kind of code? Are you mabye storing it as the `'true'` bool-string? @LuisMartins

Comment: Any progress on the problem? @LuisMartins

Comment: Sorry I totally missed SO notifications.

Comment: No problem, was just curious about it ;-) @LuisMartins