# How to filter categories by custom field?

Tags: categories, meta-query

I have a custom category page which displays child categories of the current category instead of posts. I would like to filter the child categories based on a custom field so only selected categories are displayed.
The custom field is a single check box which I added to category pages using the [Advanced Custom Fields Plugin](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).

This is the code I'm using to get the child categories:

```
$cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat_id = $cat->cat_ID;

$child_categories = get_categories(
    array(
        'parent'     => $cat_id,
        'orderby'    => 'id',
        'order'      => 'DESC',
        'hide_empty' => '0'
    )
);
```

I'm now using `meta_query` as suggested by @birgire but it's still not working. I changed the custom field from a check box to "true/false". This is the code I'm currently using:

```
$cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat_id = $cat->cat_ID;

$child_categories = get_categories(
    array(
        'parent'     => $cat_id,
        'orderby'    => 'id',
        'order'      => 'DESC',
        'hide_empty' => '0',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'show_cat',
                'value'   => 'true',
                'compare' => '=',
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use the `meta_query` attribute that uses `WP_Meta_Query` behind the scenes:

```
$child_categories = get_categories(
    array(
        'parent'     => $cat_id,
        'orderby'    => 'id',
        'order'      => 'DESC',
        'hide_empty' => '0',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'mykey',     // Adjust to your needs!
                'value'   => 'myvalue',   // Adjust to your needs!
                'compare' => '=',         // Default
            )
        )
    )
);
```

This assumes the *term meta data* to be stored in the *term meta* table, e.g. added with `add_term_meta()` or `update_term_meta()`, as of WordPress 4.4.

The previous approach was to store the term meta data in the *options* table, as seems to be the case with the ACF plugin OP is using.

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't got it to work yet. I changed the check box to "true/false". See my updated question for details.

Comment: Did you peek into the meta table in your database and verify the stored values? Maybe it's stored as `'1'`, see e.g. my answer [Inserting boolean term meta values](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/231272/26350) @jrcollins

Comment: I just checked `wp_termmeta` and it's empty: `MySQL returned an empty result set`

Comment: yes, if it's empty then that should explain why the meta query doesn't work ;-) Then the plugin you're using is storing the term meta data elsewhere @jrcollins

Comment: Ok, according to [this](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/database-structure/), the data is stored in the options table.

Comment: that's a pre WordPress 4.4 workaround to store term meta in the options table @jrcollins

Comment: So does this mean I can't query categories based on custom fields? Maybe I'll have to create the custom field myself?

Comment: You can use a term meta query if the meta data is added with `add_term_meta()` or `update_term_meta()`. @jrcollins

Comment: I got it to work by adding the custom field manually as set out in [this tutorial](https://section214.com/2016/01/adding-custom-meta-fields-to-taxonomies/). I also posted another question [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/238661/need-help-adding-custom-field-to-category) where I got some help editing the code. Thanks for your help @birgire.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. @jrcollins