# Need help adding custom field to category

Tags: categories, custom-field, metabox

I'm trying to add a custom field for categories. The custom field is a single checkbox. I can get the checkbox to show up on the forms in the create new category and edit category pages but if I check the checkbox it isn't staying checked after saving the form.

This is the code I'm using:

```
/*  Custom Field for Categories.
    ======================================== */

//Add new page

function my_taxonomy_add_meta_fields( $taxonomy ) {
    ?>
    <div class="form-field term-group">
        <label for="show_category"><?php _e( 'Show Category', 'codilight-lite' ); ?></label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="show_category" name="show_category" />
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'category_add_form_fields', 'my_taxonomy_add_meta_fields', 10, 2 );

//Edit term page

function my_taxonomy_edit_meta_fields( $term, $taxonomy ) {
    $show_category = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'show_category', true );
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field term-group-wrap">
        <th scope="row">
            <label for="show_category"><?php _e( 'Show Category', 'codilight-lite' ); ?></label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="show_category" name="show_category" value="<?php echo $show_category; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'category_edit_form_fields', 'my_taxonomy_edit_meta_fields', 10, 2 );

//Save custom meta

function my_taxonomy_save_taxonomy_meta( $term_id, $tag_id ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['show_category'] ) ) {
        update_term_meta( $term_id, 'show_category', esc_attr( $_POST['show_category'] ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'created_category', 'my_taxonomy_save_taxonomy_meta', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'edited_category', 'my_taxonomy_save_taxonomy_meta', 10, 2 );
```

I copied this code from a tutorial I found. The original code was for a text field type custom field so I think the problem probably has to do with the checkbox settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkboxes are a bit different than text inputs. The main changes below are in the save function and with handling the `checked` attribute. The value of `show_category` will be *yes* if it's been checked or an empty string for unchecked.

Keep in mind that if the `show_category` meta was never saved it will be unset, so take that into account in your code.

```
/*  Custom Field for Categories.
    ======================================== */

// Add new term page
function my_taxonomy_add_meta_fields( $taxonomy ) { ?>
    <div class="form-field term-group">
        <label for="show_category">
          <?php _e( 'Show Category', 'codilight-lite' ); ?> <input type="checkbox" id="show_category" name="show_category" value="yes" />
        </label>
    </div><?php
}
add_action( 'category_add_form_fields', 'my_taxonomy_add_meta_fields', 10, 2 );

// Edit term page
function my_taxonomy_edit_meta_fields( $term, $taxonomy ) {
    $show_category = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'show_category', true ); ?>

    <tr class="form-field term-group-wrap">
        <th scope="row">
            <label for="show_category"><?php _e( 'Show Category', 'codilight-lite' ); ?></label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="show_category" name="show_category" value="yes" <?php echo ( $show_category ) ? checked( $show_category, 'yes' ) : ''; ?>/>
        </td>
    </tr><?php
}
add_action( 'category_edit_form_fields', 'my_taxonomy_edit_meta_fields', 10, 2 );

// Save custom meta
function my_taxonomy_save_taxonomy_meta( $term_id, $tag_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST[ 'show_category' ] ) ) {
        update_term_meta( $term_id, 'show_category', 'yes' );
    } else {
        update_term_meta( $term_id, 'show_category', '' );
    }
}
add_action( 'created_category', 'my_taxonomy_save_taxonomy_meta', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'edited_category', 'my_taxonomy_save_taxonomy_meta', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working perfectly now. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Would you mind to add the codes to get the data as well for the taxonomy custom fields as well?